# If frequency shift is positive then how to interpret it?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, spacetime, observers

Let say lightning is happening at $r=r_{A}$ from center of gravity and our observer at $r=r_{B}$ with $r_{A}>r_{B}$ then if we get frequency shift is positive (by considering let say schwarzschild metric) then how does it mean means how do I interpret that. I'm wondering explanation of it means physically what does it mean?

Comment: It means that the observed frequency is higher.

Comment: Yes  ... @Javier